# How to add (Exceptions) SSL certificate in the Browser automatically

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, ssl

First of all i am sorry if this question is not valid, i am dealing with a situation where i have created the SSL certificate locally and its signed by local CA.

My frontend application is in angular and my backend application is in Spring boot when i try to connect to login from the UI then i need to add this certificate manually for that i had given a link button by clicking of that i will load the backend api in the browser

[image]

After this a popup will be open and the backend api will be loaded ,

[image]

then manually i need to click on the "Advance" and then proceed to unsafe . After all these steps certificate are getting added in the browser.

Can anyone suggest how to add this automatically without all these manual work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use below configurations to enable self signed certificate on differernt browser. Although remember, this is not for **PRODUCTION**

- **Firefox** : Go to URL `https://localhost:<port_no>` and add security exception to allow connections. If connection error still comes, Go to URL **about:config** and set value for `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to **false** and `security.mixed_content.block_display_content` to **true**.
- **Chrome** : Go to URL `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` and click on Enable and restart Chrome to allow connections.
- **IE 10 and above** : Go to URL `https://localhost:<port_no>` and add the  certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authoritiesif certificate error comes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any way using which i can add this , i mean programatically. Because, its very difficult to ask client to explain this .

Comment: for production, you need to purchase new valid SSL certificate

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a new Valid SSL Certificate. [This might help](https://www.sslshopper.com/how-to-order-an-ssl-certificate.html)